# adb install fails with error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on Android 7.0

Tags: android

```
adb install -r xxx.apk

Error: java.lanng.ArrayIndexOutBoundsException: length=0; index=0
```

Any idea on what might cause this issue?

[image: error image]

PS:I can install my APP success on Android 5.0, but got this error on Android 7.0.

Comment: try to clean your project

Comment: Did you take the build using the release setting?

Comment: Yes, I can install success on Android 5.0.